# How to realize c++ setRGB in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, colors

I have big int value `RGB = 4294967295;`
How can I set color from this value? In c++ I can use `setRGB()` method. How can I make it in iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bitwise operators like this:

```
float alpha = (intARGB >> 24) % 256;
float red = (intARGB >> 16) % 256;
float green = (intARGB >> 8) % 256;
float blue = intARGB % 256;
UIColor *theColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255. green:green/255. blue:blue/255. alpha:alpha/255.];
```

Comment: what is your actual data format? how are the components joint to an int? "It dosn't work" is not very descriptive.. also see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342114/extracting-rgb-color-components-from-integer-value

Comment: When I use your code - I have black color. In console i have this
colorNum - 4294944000 UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 0.498039

Comment: U were right. I used int, in your code, and code takes max range of int values 21..... and always gives black )

Answer (score 1):

But better to use

```
unsigned char alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xff;
unsigned char red = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
unsigned char green = (color  >> 8) &0xff;
unsigned char blue = color &0xff;
UIColor *theColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
```