# How to get hight (int16) value back to rgb form?

Tags: c++, c++11, directx-11, heightmap

I have int16 * heights[width * height] array, that hold the terrain height, i load them form a file directly as int16 *.

I need to write the heights into a bmp file.

How do i get int16 back into rgb format considering they came form a bmp file (rgb format) in the first place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to loop through your array and convert each int16 to RGB value. If `terrain`is your array

```
for (auto i=0; i<width * height; i++)
{
    auto Color = terrain[i];
    auto red = GetRValue16(color);
    auto green = GetGValue16(color);
    auto blue = GetBValue16(color);
}
```

Critical point is your definition of the three functions `GetXValue16` as RGB is usually in 4-byte representation of integer, ie int32. See also [Extracting rgb color components from integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342114/extracting-rgb-color-components-from-integer-value)